# I am creating an inventory mgt app, however when i try to return_item using_item Used i get an error # ValueError at /return_item/

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am creating an inventory mgt app, however when i try to return_item using_item Used i get an error  # ValueError at /return_item/
when i try to return an item say x was give 5 bags of cement but ended up using 2.5 x returns the 2.5 items remainining but when i try to do this gives me an error AS stated above

Django Model Definitions:

IssueItem:

```py
class IssueItem(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=true)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grouped_item = models.ForeignKey(GroupedItems, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='issue_items')
    units_issued = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.grouped_item.calculate_totals()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
return_item:
python
Copy code
class return_item(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=true)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    grouped_item = models.ForeignKey(GroupedItems, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='returned_items')
    units_returned = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.grouped_item.calculate_total()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Person
GroupedItems:
python
Copy code
class GroupedItems(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=true)
    grouped_item = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=true)
    total_units = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    units_used = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    units_available = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    Units_returned = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)

    def calculate_total(self):
        return_items = self.returned_items.all()
        self.Units_returned = return_items.aggregate(units_returned=Sum('units_returned'))['units_returned'] or 0
        self.units_used = self.units_used - self.Units_returned

    def calculate_totals(self):
        issue_items = self.issue_items.all()
        self.units_used = issue_items.aggregate(units_issued=Sum('units_issued')['units_issued'] or 0
        self.units_used = self.units_used - self.Units_returned
        self.units_available = self.total_units - self.units_used

    # Additional functions and __str__ method
Person:
python
Copy code
class Person(models.Model):
    person = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person
Problem Description:
I am facing an issue with my Django forms, particularly the ReturnItemForm. The form is designed to record the return of items by a person. When creating a new return item, I select a person, and I expect the form to display associated grouped_item options based on the person's previous issues. However, I encounter the error: "Cannot assign <IssueItem: IssueItem object (3)>: return_item.grouped_item must be a GroupedItems instance." It seems like the form is trying to assign an IssueItem instance to the grouped_item field instead of a GroupedItems instance.

ReturnItemForm:
python
Copy code
class ReturnItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # Form fields, including person, Date, and grouped_item

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReturnItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'person' in self.data:
            selected_person = self.data['person']
            self.fields['grouped_item'].queryset = IssueItem.objects.filter(person=selected_person)

    # Clean methods and other form functions
Error Message:
plaintext
Copy code
ValueError at /return_item/
Cannot assign "<IssueItem: IssueItem object (3)>": "return_item.grouped_item" must be a "GroupedItems" instance.
Expected Behavior:
I want the form to allow me to select a person, and based on that person's previous issues, display the relevant grouped_item options for return. The form should correctly assign a GroupedItems instance to the return_item.grouped_item.
```